# Using PatternTest and/or Condition to detect equal list lengths as well as list element formats

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

On searching Mathematica.SE for information about overloading functions, I came across several threads about `PatternTest` and `Condition`, and I understand the basic examples like matching by `EvenQ`. However I'm having trouble imagining how I'd use these features to implement checks having to do with "whole" lists.

---

For example, I'd like to define a function `Convert` of the form

```
Convert[quantities_, prices_] :=
```

*only* if `quantities` and `prices` are equal-length lists. In other words, if `Length[quantities] != Length[prices]` then `Convert` should behave as if undefined.

---

For a more complex example, I'd like to define an overloaded version,

```
Convert[dateQuantityList_, datePriceList_] :=
```

where `dateQuantityList` and `datePriceList` look like

```
{{{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 7}, 150},
 {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 12}, 130},
 {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 470},
 ...
}
```

and

```
{{{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 7}, 24.56},
 {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 24.58},
 ...
}
```

such that the function is only defined if all elements in `dateQuantityList[[All, 1]]` and `datePriceList[[All, 1]]` are valid `DateList`s. (Is there something like a `DateListQ`? But even supposing so, again, I'm not clear on how to apply `PatternTest` or `Condition` to a property of an entire list, not its elements...)

(The goal of the latter overload is to do a "left join" based on the date, *i.e.* discard prices that don't have corresponding dates in the quantities list, and calling the original form, `Convert[q_, p_]`. I know how to do that part using `GatherBy`—it's the `PatternTest`/`Condition` part that's completely new to me.)

I have many more overloads I'd like to write, but if I can get started with those two examples, I think I can figure the rest out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a build-in function [`DateQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Calendar/ref/DateQ.html). It is a very nice function. For example it knows that 2000 is a leap year, but 2100 is [not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar)

```
Needs["Calendar`"]
DateQ[{2000, 2, 29}]
DateQ[{2100, 2, 29}]
```

> True
>
> False

`DateQ` can take hours, minutes and seconds, but it ignores their values. See definition (there is no `` Calendar`Private`r `` in the rhs):

```
DateQ[{Calendar`Private`y_, Calendar`Private`m_, Calendar`Private`d_, 
   Calendar`Private`r___}, Calendar`Private`opts___] := 
 Module[{Calendar`Private`cal = 
    Calendar /. Flatten[{Calendar`Private`opts, Options[DateQ]}]}, 
  Calendar`Private`dateQ[Calendar`Private`y, Calendar`Private`m, 
  Calendar`Private`d, Calendar`Private`cal]]
```

However you can implement your own `dateTimeQ`

```
dateTimeQ[{h_, m_, d_, hour_, min_, sec_}] := 
  MatchQ[{h, m, d, hour, min, sec}, {__Integer}] && DateQ[{h, m, d}] &&
    0 <= hour < 24 && 0 <= min < 60 && 0 <= sec < 60;
dateTimeQ[___] := False
```

and `convert`

```
convert[quants : {{_?dateTimeQ, _Integer} ..}, prices : {{_?dateTimeQ, _Real} ..}] /; 
  Length@quants == Length@prices := OK;

quant = {{{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 7}, 150}, 
         {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 12}, 130}, 
         {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 470}};
price = {{{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 7}, 1.50}, 
         {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 1.30}, 
         {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 4.70}};
convert[quant, price]
```

> OK

Answer (score 6):

```
Convert[quantities_, prices_] /; Length[quantities] == Length[prices] := ...
```

Since `DateList` returns a list of `Length` `6` and the first five elements have `Head` `Integer` while the last has `Head` `Real` you can write your own `DateListQ`. Here is a head start:

```
 DateListQ[lis_List] := Length[lis] == 6 && VectorQ[Most[lis], IntegerQ] && 
 Head[Last[lis]] == Real
```

But note that this is an example and if you're inputting your `DateList` by hand and the last element is also an `Integer` then you can simply use:

```
DateListQ[lis_List] := Length[lis] == 6 && VectorQ[lis, IntegerQ]
```

Now for your second case, you can do something like:

```
Convert[dateQuantityList_, datePriceList_] /; Length[dateQuantityList] == Length[datePriceList] &&
VectorQ[Map[DateListQ, dateQuantityList[[All, 1]], {1}], TrueQ] &&
VectorQ[Map[DateListQ, datePriceList[[All, 1]], {1}], TrueQ] := ...
```

OR more elegantly:

```
Convert[dateQuantityList_, datePriceList_] /; Length[dateQuantityList] == Length[datePriceList] &&
VectorQ[dateQuantityList[[All,1]], DateListQ] && VectorQ[datePriceList[[All,1]], DateListQ] := ...
```

Comment: Putting the `/;` _outside_ the parameter list... brilliant. Okay, I'm gonna give this a shot and edit my question when I figure it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are endless ways to restrict the kind of arguments your `convert` function will accept. I will propose one in this answer which narrows acceptance quite a bit but not perfectly.

First, I define a set of predicates that provide quasi-validation of date-time lists. I say *quasi-validation* because I do not deal with the variation in the length of months and because my validation of years may not fit your needs. The year validation is easy to modify to accept what you consider the appropriate range.

```
yearQ[_Integer?(1970 <= # <= 2030 &)] := True
yearQ[___] := False

monthQ[_Integer?(1 <= # <= 12 &)] := True
monthQ[___] := False

dayQ[_Integer?(1 <= # <= 31 &)] := True
dayQ[___] := False

hourQ[_Integer?(0 <= # <= 23 &)] := True
hourQ[___] := False

secondQ = minuteQ;

dateQ[{_?yearQ, _?monthQ, _?dayQ, _?hourQ, _?minuteQ, _?secondQ}] := True
dateQ[___] := False
```

Given these predicates, I define two argument patterns, one for dated quantity records and the other for dated price records.

```
dateQuantity = {_?dateQ, _Integer};
datePrice = {_?dateQ, _Real};
```

Now everything is in place to write the argument pattern for `convert`

```
convert[quants : {dateQuantity ..}, prices : {datePrice ..}] /; 
  Length@quants == Length@prices := OK;
```

I think the above meets the requirements stated in your question. It certainly accepts sample data of the sort you posted, but it should get much more testing to be sure it is sufficiently restrictive.

```
quant = {
  {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 7}, 150}, 
  {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 12}, 130},
  {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 470}};
price = {
  {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 7}, 1.50}, 
  {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 1.30}, 
  {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 4.70}};
convert[quant, price]
```

> ```
> OK
> ```

But if the arguments given in the wrong order (just to examine one failure mode)_

```
convert[price, quant]
```

> ```
> convert[{{{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 7}, 1.5}, 
>          {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 1.3}, 
>          {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 4.7}}, 
>         {{{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 7}, 150}, 
>          {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 12}, 130}, 
>          {{2012, 1, 1, 9, 30, 33}, 470}}]
> ```