# Function to differentiate between date pattern and specific string format

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

I'd like to write a function that behaves one way when the argument is a *Mathematica* date, such as `{2013,12,15}`, or with added hours, minutes and seconds if necessary. And the function needs to do something different with strings that will look like

> 2013 Month 02

I see that I can specify List, as in `f[x_List]` and `f[x_String]` that will do what I want as long as I don't mess up the arguments. Is there way to be more specific about the patterns that are allowed?

Comment: You can be as specific as you want [tutorial/Putting constraints on patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html) Anything in particular?

Comment: so you only want to enter dates as lists or do you want to enter them as strings as well and differentiate between non-date strings?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34338/using-patterntest-and-or-condition-to-detect-equal-list-lengths-as-well-as-list/34339#34339

Comment: I'll just use the standard mma format since I'm reading the dates in from a file.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan Is it your earlier account: [Mitchell Kaplan](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/168/mitchell-kaplan)? If yes, the both should be merged.

Comment: @Artes They *can* be merged, but they don't necessarily have to be. :) Mitchell, if you'd like us to merge your profiles, please follow the instructions [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

There is a `DateQ` in the `Calendar` package. You can test the head of `DateList["string"]` to make your own `dateStringQ`. So `f[x_?DateQ]` and `f[x_?dateStringQ]` will do.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could do that.