# Alternatives to DateQ of Calendar Package

Tags: date-and-time

This [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34999/7252) notes that `Calendar` package has a function `DateQ` but the documentation suggests that the input is limited to a fixed format `YY,MM,DD` etc.   Is there a more robust way to check any String for date-form ?

(Self answer, below)

Comment: Use `DatePattern`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler version very similar in spirit to your own solution:

```
dateQ = Composition[Quiet, NumberQ, AbsoluteTime]
```

Comment: Very elegant. Accepted

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating your own function, the built in way to check any string is to use `StringMatchQ` and `DatePattern`. From the docs:

[ref/DatePattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DatePattern.html)

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is the right way!

Comment: Mike- nice and a +1. I'm going to stick with Szabolcs' approach as it works across all the test cases without prior knowledge of the formatting. The use-case was checking data from a spreadsheet that had a variety of date formats.

Answer (score 1):

One basic approach:

```
refDate = "Jan 1 2012";
dateQ[input_] :=
 !TrueQ@Quiet@Check[DateDifference[input, refDate], True]
```

Testing

```
test={"dog",dog,"Jan 1 2012", "January 1 2012", "1/1/2012","1/1/12","Q2 2014", "2014 Q1","2014Q2"};
dateQ/@test
(*OUTPUT*)
{False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
```

Of course, this approach could be further modified to pass values for `Calander->` and suitable `refDate` to the function.