# Import data from different webpages of the same website

Tags: list-manipulation, import, map, data-acquisition

I imported and cleaned the following datasets for england soccer league in order to have home/away rank tables and next round matches:

```
Cl = Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/homeaway.asp?league=england",
    "Data"];
Chome = Drop[Drop[Cl[[2, 4, 1]]], 1];
Caway = Drop[Drop[Cl[[2, 4, 2]]], 1];


dataENG = 
  Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=england&\
pmtype=bydate", "Data"];
Drop[Drop[Drop[Cases[dataENG, {_, _, _, _}, Infinity], -4], -1, None],
   None, -1];
Take[Table[
   If[StringContainsQ[%[[i, 2]], ":"] == True, %[[i]], ## &[]], {i, 1,
     Length[%]}], Length[teamsENG]/2];
Table[StringSplit[%[[i]], "-"], {i, 1, Length[%]}];
matchesENG = 
  Transpose[{StringTrim[%[[All, 3, 1]]], StringTrim[%[[All, 3, 2]]]}];
```

Instead of repeating the code for each european league, taking into account that the "root" of the webpages is the same for all leagues, that is:

```
"https://www.soccerstats.com/homeaway.asp?league=..."
"https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=...&\pmtype=bydate"
```

where `...=nation's name`, I would like to implement a function to map the nations with the webpages in order to have within the `Chome`, `Caway` and `matches` vectors the data of all main european leagues.

Comment: What is `teamsENG`?

Comment: Sorry, `teamsENG=Chome[[All,2]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

To get a list containing the Home values for all of the countries as separate sub lists:

```
allHome = countryMatches // Map[KeyTake[#, "Home"] &] // Catenate
```

Similarly for any other key in the association.

---

I modified the code so it is easier (at least for me) to understand and wrapped it in a function that returns an `Association` of associations that hold match and team data.

```
matchesFor[country_] := Module[
  {data, home, away, teams, allGames, byDate, matches1, matches2, allMatches,
   selectedMatches, matchTeams},

  data = Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/homeaway.asp?league=" <> country, "Data"];
  home = data[[2, 4, 1, 2 ;;]];
  away = data[[2, 4, 2, 2 ;;]];
  teams = home[[All, 2]];

  byDate = Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?pmtype=bydate&league=" <> country, "Data"];
  matches1 = byDate[[2, 3, 2, 1, All, 1 ;; -2]] // Select[Length@# == 3 &];
  matches2 = byDate[[2, 3, 2, 2, 1, All, 1 ;; -2]];
  allMatches = matches1~Join~matches2;

  selectedMatches = allMatches // Select[StringContainsQ[#[[2]], ":"] &] // 
     Take[#, Length[teams]/2] & // Map[StringSplit[#, " - "] &];

  matchTeams = selectedMatches[[All, 3]];

  <|country -> <|"Teams" -> teams, "Home" -> home, "Away" -> away, 
     "Matches" -> allMatches, "SelectedMatches" -> selectedMatches, 
     "MatchTeams" -> matchTeams|>|>
  ]
```

Then `Map` the function over the list of countries you are interested in and combine the associations.

```
countryMatches = matchesFor /@ {"England", "France", "Germany"} // Association;
```

To get the data for a country

```
countryMatches["England"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rohit! 
Actually I would need to have all the main european leagues data within three big vectors only, that is `Chome`, `Caway` and `matches`.
Basically, I would like to have 
`Chome={ChomeENG,ChomeITA,ChomeGER}` 
by manipulating website pages root with a function which creates it. And so on for `Caway` and `matches`, instead of doing it by repeating the same code form to import data from all leagues to create `n` subvectors like `ChomeENG`, `ChomeITA`, `ChomeGER`(etc.) with several code strings equal to each others unless for country name.

Comment: Mick, I am not sure exactly what you mean. Since the `countryMatches` association has the data for all countries, it is easy to combine data from different countries. I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Rohit, awesome! It works! Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi Rohit, I posted a similar issue here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216991/implement-a-function-which-import-data-from-the-same-webpage-root
can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test the model, I should implement within the `matchesFor` function the importation of the already played matches dataset ordered by rounds for all leagues (here reported Italian league code from the webpage that already does this filter):

```
d = Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=italy&pmtype=\bygameweek","Data"];
t1=Table[{d[[2,3,2,1,1,i,1,1,1]],Drop[Drop[Drop[d[[2,3,2,1,1,i,1]],1],None,1],None,-1]},{i,1,Length[d[[2,3,2,1,1]]]}];
t2=Table[{d[[2,3,2,1,2,i,1,1,1]],Drop[Drop[Drop[d[[2,3,2,1,2,i,1]],1],None,1],None,-1]},{i, 1, 4}];
Join[t1, t2];
```

I guess it should be filtered also by `allGames` variable with some `If` condition?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "filtered". BTW your code is missing Round 24. Always better to use `Map` rather than `Table` with hardcoded limits. Also, please do not use answers to ask new questions, Ask a new question and link to the original. The moderators are likely to delete this and your previous answer as "Not an answer".

Comment: ok, sorry. I'll post a new question, thank you!

Comment: I hope it is understandable what I would like to do, I posted a new question here:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215230/iterative-comparison-between-different-vectors

Comment: I posted an answer to your other question.

Comment: Hi Rohit, something is wrong with importing data and bydate with code nowadays.. can you help me?

Comment: Hi Nate I don’t have time now. Will take a look over the weekend.

Comment: The structure has changed. Try `allMatches = byDate[[2, 4, 1]]`. Also, would be nice if you could upvote my first answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rohit, I tried the ```allMatches``` new vector, It works but the next ```SelectedMatch``` step doesn't work . At the same time, I tried to change ```matches1``` and ```matches2``` at the same manner but the ```Select``` option after ```matches1``` is still not working too. How could I rearrange the code to the new structure?