# Iterative comparison between different vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, map, iterators, iteration

I have some soccer outcomes for each league round to import in a data form similar to that:

```
results={{round1,{{team1,team2,4,0},{team3,team4,2,1}}},{round2,{{team2,team3,2,4}, {team4,team1,1,3}}},{round3,{{team1,team3,0,1},{team4,team2,2,2}}}};
```

I should build a temporany rank matrix after each round with the following data (here the example for after the second round):

```
{{team,home,hgscored,hgconceded,agscored,agconceded},{team1,1,4,0,1,3,1},{team2,1,2,4,1,0,4},{team3,1,2,1,1,4,2},{team4,1,1,3,1,1,2}}
```

to take in order to derive a vector with, for instance, the following outcome percentage for the next round:

```
forecast={{T1,T2,1,X,2},{team1,team3,54%,27%,19%},{team4,team2,42%,24%,42%}};
```

and iteratively comparise `forecast` vector prediction with the related round played whose outcomes are in `results` vector, collecting everithing on a vector in order to test the model: how many events were correctly predicted by forecast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Patterns are the key to this one.

Just pick off the games themselves from the results.

```
games = Partition[Flatten@results[[All, 2]], 4]

(* {{team1, team2, 4, 0}, {team3, team4, 2, 1}, {team2, team3, 2, 4}, 
    {team4, team1, 1, 3}, {team1, team3, 0, 1}, {team4, team2, 2, 2}} *)
```

Define this pattern and the replacement right hand side. The `th` is "team home" ,etc. It parses out the home and away teams and sets up the data. I didn't know what your `home` meant, so I just generate records with 5 fields.

```
patt = {th_, ta_, ths_, tas_} :> {{th, 1, ths, tas, 0, 0, 0}, {ta, 0, 0, 0, 1, tas, ths}}
```

Run it over the games

```
res = Cases[games, patt]

(* {{{team1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {team2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4}}, 
    {{team3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {team4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}}, 
    {{team2, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {team3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2}},
    {{team4, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {team1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1}}, 
    {{team1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {team3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}},
    {{team4, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {team2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2}}} *)
```

Do a `GatherBy` on team names after flattening things out.

```
res2 = GatherBy[Partition[Flatten@res, 7], First];

(* {{{team1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {team1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1}, {team1, 1, 0,  1, 0, 0, 0}}, 
    {{team2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4}, {team2, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {team2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2}}, 
    {{team3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {team3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2}, {team3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}}, 
    {{team4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}, {team4, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {team4, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0}}} *)
```

Sum up the values for each team, and label by team.

```
res3 =Flatten@{First@First@#, Rest[Total[#]]} & /@ res2

(* {{team1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1}, 
    {team2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6}, 
    {team3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2}, 
    {team4, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2}} *)

Join[{{team, home, hgscored, hgconceded, away, agscored, agconceded}},   res3] // TableForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 \text{team} & \text{home} & \text{hgscored} & \text{hgconceded} & \text{away} & \text{agscored} & \text{agconceded} \\
 \text{team1} & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
 \text{team2} & 1 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 6 \\
 \text{team3} & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 2 \\
 \text{team4} & 2 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Not sure the details on your analysis of the data, but this gets it in a form you can work with.

Comment: Thank you MikeY, unfortunately this is not what I looked for. I should need "home" and "away" which are, respectively, the number of the matches played by each team at home and away. I tried to change `patt` in: `patt = {h_, ths_, thc_, a_, tas_, 
    tac_} -> {{h, ths, thc, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, a, tas, tas}}` but it doesn't work. Moreover, I should build an above-mentioned rank matrix as it was an iterator where each round rank is the sum of it and the previous ones, in order to derive other parameters from it, put in `forecast` and then comparising `results` and `forecast` for each round

Comment: @Mick, I updated the answer to include the number of home and away games. Still not sure I am following on the vector aspect.

Comment: MikeY, perfect for home/away, thank you! And from the way to built the rank also, the matrix representation is that I thougth! The only way is that I should need it after the first round, then after the second, then after the third and so on, because I should insert it in a iterative `For` or `Do cicle to derive `forecast`. I guess that `res3` is just for the final rank.. should I change `res3` in: `res3 =Flatten@{First@First@#, Rest[Total[#]**[[i]]]**} & /@ res2`?

Comment: You should be using RuleDelayed in your definition of `patt` to properly localize Symbols.

Comment: Where would not using `:>` blow up on me? I tried both and got the same answer...not sure.

Comment: It is a matter of good programming practice.  Using `->` instead of `:>` will evaluate any global assignments to the pattern names on the right hand side.  Try for example defining `tas = 7` before the rest of your code.  Where you *don't* need this behavior it is best to use `:>` instead.  (by the way: good answer and +1)

Comment: Thanks! I've gotten burned with a `Random[ ]` on the right side of a rule, so knew it could be important. Fixed my entry.