# Implement a function which import data from the same webpage root

Tags: fitting, import, time-series

I would like to implement a function to import several dataset from the same website source, where for each dataset it changes just one word on the website address.

Here the website: `https://statistichecoronavirus.it/regioni-coronavirus-italia/.../`
where `...` represents the part to change in order to get each dataset.
I would like to have the following variable vectors from each webpage:

```
total infected
total active cases 
total deaths
total healed
daily increment infected
daily incremental active cases
daily increment deaths
daily increment healed
```

I tried to write the following, but it doesn't work:

```
covid19[region_] := 
 Module[{data, process, date, infected, cases, deaths, healed},
  data = Import[
    "https://statistichecoronavirus.it/regioni-coronavirus-italia/"<>region <> "/", "Data"];
  process[s_String] := Module[{d = StringSplit[s, " "][[1]]}, 
    If[StringContainsQ[d, "/"], 
     DateObject[{d <> "/2020", {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}], 
     ToExpression[StringReplace[d, "." -> ""]]]];
  process[s_Integer] := s (*to process the last string*);
  date = Map[process, data[[2, All, ;; -2]], {2}][[All, 1]];
  infected= Map[process, data[[2, All, ;; -2]], {2}][[All, 2]];
  cases = Map[process, data[[2, All, ;; -2]], {2}][[All, 3]];
  deaths = Map[process, data[[2, All, ;; -2]], {2}][[All, 4]];
  healed = Map[process, data[[2, All, ;; -2]], {2}][[All, 5]];
  <|region -> <|"Infected" -> infected, "Cases" -> cases, "Deaths" ->deaths, "Healed" -> healed|>|>]
status = covid19 /@ {"Lombardia", "Sicilia"} // Association;
```

That's what I've done without functional programming bases:

```
ClearAll;
data = Import["https://statistichecoronavirus.it/coronavirus-italia/",
    "Data"];
Table[Drop[%[[2, i]], -1], {i, 1, Length[%[[2]]] - 1}];
temp = Table[StringReplace[%[[i]], "." -> ""], {i, 1, Length[%]}];
StringExtract[##, 1] & /@ temp;
Join[{data[[1, 2 ;; All]]}, 
  ToExpression[%[[All, 2 ;; All]]], {ToExpression[
    Drop[data[[2, -1]], -1][[2 ;; All]]]}];
tot = Transpose[
   Insert[% // Transpose, 
    Flatten[{"Data", StringExtract[##, 1] & /@ temp[[All, 1]], 
      "20/02"}], 1]];
contagi = tot[[2 ;; All, 2]];
casi = tot[[2 ;; All, 3]];
morti = tot[[2 ;; All, 4]];
guariti = tot[[2 ;; All, 5]];
Join[{data[[1, 2 ;; All]]}, 
  ToExpression[
   ArrayReshape[
    StringCases[StringJoin[temp], 
     Shortest["(+" ~~ x__ ~~ ")"] -> x], {Length[temp], 
     4}]], {ToExpression[Drop[data[[2, -1]], -1][[2 ;; All]]]}];
par = Transpose[
   Insert[% // Transpose, 
    Flatten[{"Data", StringExtract[##, 1] & /@ temp[[All, 1]], 
      "20/02"}], 1]];
\[CapitalDelta]contagi = tot[[2 ;; All, 2]];
\[CapitalDelta]casi = tot[[2 ;; All, 3]];
\[CapitalDelta]morti = tot[[2 ;; All, 4]];
\[CapitalDelta]guariti = tot[[2 ;; All, 5]];
date = Table[
  DateObject[{tot[[i, 1]] <> "/2020", {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], {i, 
   2, Length[tot]}]
G1 = TemporalData[contagi, {date}];
G2 = TemporalData[casi, {date}];
G3 = TemporalData[morti, {date}];
G4 = TemporalData[guariti, {date}];
Show[ListLinePlot[G1], ListLinePlot[G2], ListLinePlot[G3], 
 ListLinePlot[G4]]
Interpolation[G1, InterpolationOrder -> 4]
```

My final goal is to get several interpolation and bestfit function for each region.
I would like to avoid repeating it for each "region".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** Plot data for several regions

```
provinces = {"lombardia", "sicilia"};
dataByProvince = covid19Italy /@ provinces;

dataByProvince //
  Map[(KeyTake[#, {"date", "total infected"}] &), #, {2}] & //   
  Values //
  Flatten[#, 1] & //
  DateListPlot[#,
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
   PlotLegends -> Capitalize@provinces,
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
   PlotLabel -> Style["COVID-19 Italy - Total Infected by Province", 14, Black]] &
```

[image]

---

That code looks quite complicated. Here is an alternative (and I think, simpler) implementation.

```
covid19Italy[region_] := 
 Module[{header, convertDelta, insertZero, data, processedData},

  header = {"date", "total infected", "total infected change", 
    "total deaths", "total deaths change", "total healed", 
    "total healed change"};

  insertZero[n_] := ToString[n] <> " (+0)";

  convertDelta[s_] := 
   StringReplace[s, {"(" -> "", ")" -> ""}] // StringSplit // 
    ToExpression;

  data = Import["https://statistichecoronavirus.it/regioni-coronavirus-italia/" <> 
      region <> "/", "Data"][[2, 2]];

  processedData = 
   data //
       MapAt[StringReplace[" In aggiornamento" -> ""] /*
         (DateObject[{# <> "/2020", {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}] &), #, {All, 1}] & //                 
      MapAt[insertZero, #, {-1, 2 ;;}] & //
     MapAt[convertDelta, #, {All, 2 ;;}] & //
    Map[Flatten];
  <|region -> (AssociationThread[header -> #] &) /@ processedData|>]

lombardia = covid19Italy["lombardia"];

lombardia // Map[KeyTake[#, {"date", "total infected"}] &] // DateListPlot
```

[image]

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1909687)

Comment: Really Rohit, thank you, for the brilliant solution and the upmentioned link also.
I must confess that I can't understand perfectly all the local steps of the covid19Italy function and your solutions are for me the best possible case study to learn programming in Mathematica environment.
I think to comparise several region DateListPlots with Show function; should I already assign different colors within DateListPlot function (I don't know how in this "//" form) or can I assign it within Show function (I tried in this way but it doesn't works)?

Comment: Added an example showing how to plot data for multiple provinces.

Comment: Rohit, could you help me please?
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218408/optimization-of-storages-capacity