# Automate Poisson Football Scores Prediction

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, distributions, automation

I would like to automate a simple poisson football scores predictions process.

I started by importing and cleaning home and away England League team tables data to work on it with Poisson distribution:

```
ClearAll;
Cl = Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/homeaway.asp?league=england",
    "Data"];
Chome = Drop[Drop[Cl[[2, 3, 1]]], 1];
Caway = Drop[Drop[Cl[[2, 3, 2]]], 1];
teamsENG = Chome[[All, 2]];
```

I imported also the next round of the matches to be played respect to the date of the initial data importing:

```
dataENG = 
  Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=england&\
pmtype=bydate", "Data"];
Drop[Drop[Drop[Cases[dataENG, {_, _, _, _}, Infinity], -4], -1, None],
   None, -1];
Take[Table[
   If[StringContainsQ[%[[i, 2]], ":"] == True, %[[i]], ## &[]], {i, 1,
     Length[%]}], Length[teamsENG]/2];
Table[StringSplit[%[[i]], "-"], {i, 1, Length[%]}];
matchesENG = 
  Transpose[{StringTrim[%[[All, 3, 1]]], StringTrim[%[[All, 3, 2]]]}];
```

Now, I create two vectors of the poisson parameters for home teams goal score (`A`) and away teams goal score (`B`) related to next round matches:

```
A = ConstantArray[0, Length[teamsENG]];
B = ConstantArray[0, Length[teamsENG]];
Do[Do[Table[
    If[matchesENG[[i, 1]] == Chome[[j, 2]] && 
      matchesENG[[i, 2]] == Caway[[k, 2]], 
     A[[j]] = 
      A[[j]] + 
       N[((Chome[[j, 7]]/Chome[[j, 3]]) + (Caway[[k, 8]]/
             Caway[[k, 3]]))/2], ## &[]], {k, 1, 
     Length[teamsENG]}], {j, 1, Length[teamsENG]}], {i, 1, 
   Length[matchesENG]}];
Do[Do[Table[
    If[matchesENG[[i, 1]] == Chome[[j, 2]] && 
      matchesENG[[i, 2]] == Caway[[k, 2]], 
     B[[k]] = 
      B[[k]] + 
       N[((Chome[[j, 8]]/Chome[[j, 3]]) + (Caway[[k, 7]]/
             Caway[[k, 3]]))/2], ## &[]], {k, 1, 
     Length[teamsENG]}], {j, 1, Length[teamsENG]}], {i, 1, 
   Length[matchesENG]}];
```

By doing that, I can't transform fractions in a decimal form although I used N operator.

Anyway, the next step is to define the Poisson probability density function  `p[m_, x_] := PDF[PoissonDistribution[m, x]` for home (`m=A`) and away (`m=B`)teams and, by taking into account the next matches round thanks to the vector `matchesENG`, define the product between `p[A, x]*p[B, x]` being able to recognize the actual home team and away team for each match and displaying the scores.

I don't understand how to execute this last part of the code by keeping the right home team and away team for each match.

Taking into account what above mentioned, I would like to automate the code for all european leagues by manipulating lists in a way similar to this I got answered to obtain goalscored for England and German leagues:

```
dateQ = Composition[Quiet, NumberQ, AbsoluteTime]; (*https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49112/46490*)

countries = {"ENG", "GER"};
Evaluate[countrydata /@ countries] = With[
  {data = Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=" <> # <> "&pmtype=bydate", "Data"]}, 
  Cases[
    data,
    {_?dateQ, teams_?(Not@*StringContainsQ[DigitCharacter]), score_, _} :> MapAt[ToExpression, StringTrim@StringSplit[#, " - "] & /@ {teams, score}, 2],
    ∞
  ]
] & /@ {"england", "germany"};

goalsfor = Join @@ Table[
  (#1[[2]] -> #2) & @@@ Total[#, {2}] &@GatherBy[Join @@ (Transpose /@ countrydata[country]), First],
  {country, countries}
] // Association
```

But this is a next step I guess..

Comment: The reason `N` does not work is that the argument is a `String`. e.g. `InputForm@A` is `{0, 0.5*(" 14 "/" 11 " + ...`. Use `ToExpression` to convert the strings to integers.

Comment: Thank you Rohit!

Answer (score 1):

I modified code as follows to obtain decimal form:

```
ClearAll;
Cl = Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/homeaway.asp?league=england",
    "Data"];
Chome = Drop[Drop[Cl[[2, 3, 1]]], 1];
Caway = Drop[Drop[Cl[[2, 3, 2]]], 1];
teamsENG = Chome[[All, 2]];
dataENG = 
  Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=england&\
pmtype=bydate", "Data"];
Drop[Drop[Drop[Cases[dataENG, {_, _, _, _}, Infinity], -4], -1, None],
   None, -1];
Take[Table[
   If[StringContainsQ[%[[i, 2]], ":"] == True, %[[i]], ## &[]], {i, 1,
     Length[%]}], Length[teamsENG]/2];
Table[StringSplit[%[[i]], "-"], {i, 1, Length[%]}];
matchesENG = 
  Transpose[{StringTrim[%[[All, 3, 1]]], StringTrim[%[[All, 3, 2]]]}];
A = ConstantArray[0, Length[teamsENG]];
B = ConstantArray[0, Length[teamsENG]];
Do[Do[Table[
    If[matchesENG[[i, 1]] == Chome[[j, 2]] && 
      matchesENG[[i, 2]] == Caway[[k, 2]], 
     A[[j]] = 
      A[[j]] + 
       N[((ToExpression[Chome[[j, 7]]]/
             ToExpression[Chome[[j, 3]]]) + (ToExpression[
              Caway[[k, 8]]]/ToExpression[Caway[[k, 3]]]))/
         2], ## &[]], {k, 1, Length[teamsENG]}], {j, 1, 
    Length[teamsENG]}], {i, 1, Length[matchesENG]}];
Do[Do[Table[
    If[matchesENG[[i, 1]] == Chome[[j, 2]] && 
      matchesENG[[i, 2]] == Caway[[k, 2]], 
     B[[k]] = 
      B[[k]] + 
       N[((ToExpression[Chome[[j, 8]]]/
             ToExpression[Chome[[j, 3]]]) + (ToExpression[
              Caway[[k, 7]]]/ToExpression[Caway[[k, 3]]]))/
         2], ## &[]], {k, 1, Length[teamsENG]}], {j, 1, 
    Length[teamsENG]}], {i, 1, Length[matchesENG]}];
```

I still can't obtain poisson value and ordinate them respect to next matches.
I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
p1[m1_, x_] := 
 PDF[PoissonDistribution[Round[Do[A[[i]], {i, 1, Length[A]}]]], x]
p2[m2_, x_] := 
 PDF[PoissonDistribution[Round[Do[B[[i]], {i, 1, Length[B]}]]], x]
hprob = Table[p[A, x], {x, 0, 10}]
aprob = Table[p[B, x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Any help?