# Automate table to display figures

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, output-formatting

With reference to the post [Automate Poisson Football Scores Prediction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212730/automate-poisson-football-scores-prediction/212932#212932), I succeded in defining the Poisson probability density function for home (`μh=A`) and away (`μa=B`) teams, but cannot create a table/matrix taking into account the next matches round thanks to the vector matchesENG and the product between `p[A, x]*p[B, x]` because I am not able to recognize the actual home team and away team for each match and displaying the scores.
Here the complete nb.

```
ClearAll;
Cl = Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/homeaway.asp?league=england",
    "Data"];
Chome = Drop[Drop[Cl[[2, 4, 1]]], 1];
Caway = Drop[Drop[Cl[[2, 4, 2]]], 1];
teamsENG = Chome[[All, 2]];
dataENG = 
  Import["https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=england&\
pmtype=bydate", "Data"];
Drop[Drop[Drop[Cases[dataENG, {_, _, _, _}, Infinity], -4], -1, None],
   None, -1];
Take[Table[
   If[StringContainsQ[%[[i, 2]], ":"] == True, %[[i]], ## &[]], {i, 1,
     Length[%]}], Length[teamsENG]/2];
Table[StringSplit[%[[i]], "-"], {i, 1, Length[%]}];
matchesENG = 
  Transpose[{StringTrim[%[[All, 3, 1]]], StringTrim[%[[All, 3, 2]]]}];
A = ConstantArray[0, Length[teamsENG]];
B = ConstantArray[0, Length[teamsENG]];
Do[Do[Table[
    If[matchesENG[[i, 1]] == Chome[[j, 2]] && 
      matchesENG[[i, 2]] == Caway[[k, 2]], 
     A[[j]] = 
      A[[j]] + 
       N[((ToExpression[Chome[[j, 7]]]/
             ToExpression[Chome[[j, 3]]]) + (ToExpression[
              Caway[[k, 8]]]/ToExpression[Caway[[k, 3]]]))/
         2], ## &[]], {k, 1, Length[teamsENG]}], {j, 1, 
    Length[teamsENG]}], {i, 1, Length[matchesENG]}];
Do[Do[Table[
    If[matchesENG[[i, 1]] == Chome[[j, 2]] && 
      matchesENG[[i, 2]] == Caway[[k, 2]], 
     B[[k]] = 
      B[[k]] + 
       N[((ToExpression[Chome[[j, 8]]]/
             ToExpression[Chome[[j, 3]]]) + (ToExpression[
              Caway[[k, 7]]]/ToExpression[Caway[[k, 3]]]))/
         2], ## &[]], {k, 1, Length[teamsENG]}], {j, 1, 
    Length[teamsENG]}], {i, 1, Length[matchesENG]}];
μhome = Transpose[{teamsENG, A}];
μaway = Transpose[{teamsENG, B}];
ph[μh_, xh_] := PDF[PoissonDistribution[μh], xh];
Gh = Table[
   If[μhome[[i, 2]] > 0, {μhome[[i, 1]], 
     Table[ph[μhome[[i, 2]], x], {x, 0, 10}]}, ## &[]], {i, 1, 
    Length[μhome]}];
pa[μa_, xa_] := PDF[PoissonDistribution[μa], xa];
Ga = Table[
   If[μaway[[i, 2]] > 0, {μaway[[i, 1]], 
     Table[ph[μaway[[i, 2]], x], {x, 0, 10}]}, ## &[]], {i, 1, 
    Length[μaway]}];
```

I tried something like that to take next match home/away teams, but I cannot organize/display the result in a very clear and understandable manner.

```
X = Table[
   Table[If[
     matchesENG[[i, 1]] == Gh[[j, 1]] && 
      matchesENG[[i, 2]] == Ga[[k, 1]], 
     Table[Gh[[j, 2, l]]*Ga[[k, 2, m]], {l, 1, 10}, {m, 1, 
       10}], ## &[]], {j, 1, Length[Gh]}, {k, 1, Length[Ga]}], {i, 1, 
    Length[matchesENG]}];
```

Please, any help?

Comment: How is the title of the post related to the content? Do we really have to read all the code in the first block? I really did not get your problem. Please get into the habit of writing _minimal_ examples.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to simplify the problem

Comment: Mick, the setup in your answer below may be a better candidate for a _minimal_ example. Perhaps you can post that answer as the question?

Comment: Sure, how can I do? Actually, I tried to do it before but it was not successful so I posted it as a new question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214275/create-table-from-dataset?noredirect=1#comment548329_214275    ..I’m sorry, I am new in the forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `matches`, `goalshome` and `goalsaway` from user12590788's self-answer to define three associations:

```
{asmatches, ashome, asaway} = Association[Rule@@@#] & /@ {matches, goalshome, goalsaway};
```

Use `Outer` to get a table of products of associated entries:

```
outer = Outer[Times, ashome @ #, asaway @ #2] &;
```

Prepend the table with a column containing home team:

```
addfirstColumn = Join[List /@ {#, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove}, outer@##, 2] &;
```

Add a row containing the visitor team name before and a blank row after each block:

```
kvm = Join[{{#2, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}}, 
    addfirstColumn @ ##, 
   {{"", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}}] &;
```

Use `KeyValueMap` to map `kvm` to `asmatches`:

```
grid = Join @@ KeyValueMap[kvm, asmatches];

Grid[grid, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All, BaseStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

To combine all steps into a function that creates the desired grid given three lists as input:

```
ClearAll[makeGrid]
makeGrid[ml_, ghl_, gal_] :=  Module[{asm, ash, asa, outer, 
    headerC, headerR, blankR, kvM,
    assocs = Map[Apply[AssociationThread]@*Transpose] @ {ml, ghl, gal}},
  {asm, ash, asa} = assocs;
  outer = Outer[Times, ash@#, asa @#2] &;
  headerC = List /@ Join[{#}, ConstantArray[SpanFromAbove, Length[ash@#] - 1]] &;
  headerR = {Join[{#}, ConstantArray[SpanFromLeft, Length@asa@#]]} &;
  blankR = {Join[{""}, ConstantArray[SpanFromLeft, Length@asa@#]]} &;
  kvM = Join[headerR@#2, Join[headerC @#, outer@##, 2], blankR@#2] &;
  Join @@ KeyValueMap[kvM, asm]]
```

Use `makeGrid[matches, goalshome, goalsaway]` as first argument in `Grid` and add the desired grid options:

```
Grid[makeGrid[matches, goalshome, goalsaway], 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, BaseStyle -> 16]
```

> same picture as above

An alternative, and simpler, approach is to create a separate grid for each pair in `matches` and use [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) to label each grid:

```
{ashome, asaway} = Association[Rule @@@ #] & /@ {goalshome, goalsaway};

Column[matches /. {a_, b_} :> Labeled[
   Grid[Outer[Times, ashome @ a, asaway @ b], Dividers -> All], 
   {a, b},
   {Left, Top}]]
```

[image]

**Note:** Both methods work if the lengths of the goals lists are not the same for all teams:

```
SeedRandom[1]
matches2 = Partition[RandomSample[Array[Symbol["team" <> ToString@#] &, 10]],  2];

goalshome2 = Thread[matches2[[All, 1]] -> Table[RandomReal[1, RandomInteger[{2, 5}]], 5]];

goalsaway2 = Thread[matches2[[All, -1]] -> Table[RandomReal[1, RandomInteger[{2, 5}]], 5]];

{ashome2, asaway2} = Association[Rule @@@ #] & /@ {goalshome2, goalsaway2};

Column[matches2 /. {a_, b_} :> 
   Labeled[Grid[Outer[Times, ashome2@a, asaway2@b], 
     Dividers -> All], {a, b}, {Left, Top}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing kglr, really thank you! Actually obtaining this grid is just an intermediate step, the final output should be to collect for each match the probabilities of the following events: 1 (home win, which means sum of all terms under matrix principal diagonal); X (draw, which means sum of all terms which makes matrix principal diagonal); 2 (away win, which means sum of all terms upper matrix principal diagonal); under/over “nr. goals” (for instance, if nr.goals=2, it means the sum of terms over/under the matrix secondary diagonal). Please, can you help me coding and display it on a table?

Comment: The goal is to apped next to matches vector {team i, team j} the events probabilities vector: {1, X, 2 under 1.5, over 1.5, under 2.5, over 2.5, under 3.5, over 3.5}. Anyway, the length of goal list should be equal for all teams because every grid term represents the probability of an exact score for that match and I thought to consider a range Of six row/columns (0,1,2,3,4,5 goals) to derive probabilities of events 1,X,etc. by summing these.

Comment: @Mick, maybe you can post a new question on what you want to do in the next step, using a minimal example like: for example, want to re-organize the input $\left\{\text{team1},\text{team2},\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 d & e & f \\
 g & h & i \\
\end{array}
\right)\right\}$ into a form `output = {1,X, 2...}` showing how you map the input elements  to the elements of desired output.

Comment: Thank you kglr, I’ll try soon and then I’ll post here the link for this next step new question!!!

Comment: Hi kglr, here the link for the new question topic:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214443/code-a-function-to-obtain-an-output-table-from-an-input-dataset-taking-into-acco

Answer (score 0):

I have a League with 6 teams and this vectors:

```
matches={{team1,team4},{team3,team2},{team5,team6}}

goalshome={{team1,{0.129812,0.265033,0.270555}},
{team3,{0.274812,0.354966,0.229249}},
{team5,{0.25284,0.347654,0.239012}}}

goalsaway={{team2,{0.129812,0.265033,0.270555}},
    {team4,{0.274812,0.354966,0.229249}},
    {team6,{0.25284,0.347654,0.239012}}}
```

I have to obtain automatically the following Table (assume `goalshome=gh` and `goalsaway=ga`):

```
                                            team 4
       gh[[1,2,1]]*ga[[2,2,1]]  gh[[1,2,1]]*ga[[2,2,2]]  gh[[1,2,1]]*ga[[2,2,3]]
team 1 gh[[1,2,2]]*ga[[2,2,1]]  gh[[1,2,2]]*ga[[2,2,2]]  gh[[1,2,2]]*ga[[2,2,3]]
       gh[[1,2,3]]*ga[[2,2,1]]  gh[[1,2,3]]*ga[[2,2,2]]  gh[[1,2,3]]*ga[[2,2,3]]

                                            team 2
       gh[[2,2,1]]*ga[[1,2,1]]  gh[[2,2,1]]*ga[[1,2,2]]  gh[[2,2,1]]*ga[[1,2,3]]
team 3 gh[[2,2,2]]*ga[[1,2,1]]  gh[[2,2,2]]*ga[[1,2,2]]  gh[[2,2,2]]*ga[[1,2,3]]
       gh[[2,2,3]]*ga[[1,2,1]]  gh[[2,2,3]]*ga[[1,2,2]]  gh[[2,2,3]]*ga[[1,2,3]]

                                            team 6
       gh[[3,2,1]]*ga[[3,2,1]]  gh[[3,2,1]]*ga[[3,2,2]]  gh[[3,2,1]]*ga[[1,2,3]]
team 5 gh[[3,2,2]]*ga[[3,2,1]]  gh[[3,2,2]]*ga[[3,2,2]]  gh[[3,2,2]]*ga[[1,2,3]]
       gh[[3,2,3]]*ga[[3,2,1]]  gh[[3,2,3]]*ga[[3,2,2]]  gh[[3,2,3]]*ga[[1,2,3]]
```

To do that, first I have to identify (from `matches`) `team i VS team j` in order to apply `gh[[i,2,l]*ga[[j,2,m]]`, but I cannot code it.