# Code a function to obtain an output table from an input dataset taking into account some rules

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation, map

Good morning,
I have an input dataset in the following form:

```
data={{{team1,team4},{{0.0356739,0.0460788,0.0297593,0.048},{0.0728342,0.0940777,0.0607586,0.052},{0.0743518,0.0960378,0.0620245,0.0238}}},{{team3,team2},{{0.0356739,0.0728342,0.0743518,0.0238},{0.0460788,0.0940777,0.0960378,0.0133},{0.0297593, 0.0607586,0.0620245,0.0148}}},{{team5,team6},{{0.0639281,0.0879008,0.0604318,0.01438},{0.0879008,0.120863,0.0830935,0.03438},{0.0604318,0.0830935,0.0571267,0.05438}}}}
```

I would like to create a function to obtain the following output table:

```
output={data[[k,1]],1,X,2}
```

where the kth `data[[k,1]]={team_k1,team_k2}` represents the kth match and the kth event 1,X,2 represents the events home victory, draw, away victory for the kth match.
So, the rules for these events are the following:

```
1: If[i>j,Sum[data[[k,2,i,j]]...{i,1,Length[data[[1,2,1]]]},{j,1,Length[data[[1,2,1]]]}
X: If[i=j,Sum[data[[k,2,i,j]]...{i,1,Length[data[[1,2,1]]]},{j,1,Length[data[[1,2,1]]]}
2: If[i<j,Sum[data[[k,2,i,j]]...{i,1,Length[data[[1,2,1]]]},{j,1,Length[data[[1,2,1]]]}
```

Comment: Mick, please visit [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) re voting/accepting answers and [FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)  for general questions about stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[tabulate]
tabulate = Flatten[{#, Total[Join @@ UpperTriangularize[#2, 1]], Tr@#2, 
       Total[Join @@ UpperTriangularize[#2, -1]]}] & @@@ # &;

headers = {"home", "away", "1", "X", "2"};

TableForm[tabulate@data, TableHeadings -> {None, headers}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Prepend[tabulate@data, headers], Dividers -> {All, {All, 2 -> Thick}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kglr! Would there be any way to associate a color scale depending on the value of the pecentage on the table?

Comment: @Mick, that's another good question (with many possible answers). It is generally expected that new requirements posted in comments should be edited into the original question or, better yet, posted as a new question.  A quick way is to color the numbers in `tabulate[data]` using `ReplaceAll`: e.g.,  `styledtable= tabulate[data] /.  x_?NumericQ :> Style[x, ColorData["Rainbow"]@x]`

Comment: Hi kglr, can you help me please?
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218408/optimization-of-storages-capacity